# Upgrading WordPress Timber Plugin from 1.7.0 to 1.9.4

Tags: timber

Do you think upgrading will break functionality or adversely change the look and feel of the website? Is there any way to revert to the previous version of this plugin after upgrade if things go wrong?

Have been asked to manage a WordPress site that uses Timber and Twig. First time using Timber templating solution. All other plugins, as well as WordPress site, have been upgraded to the latest versions.

Worried that the Timber upgrade will require twig file code changes.

Ideally would like to make an effortless upgrade, where nothing visually changes at the site and no code changes are required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always get previous versions from (scroll to the bottom):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/timber-library/advanced/

In general, we don't recommend upgrading for upgrade's sake. The good news is that if there are changes to the Twig files, they're likely to be minor — but even so, there's not much upside to going from 1.7 => 1.9 unless you're in active development and will be adding new features/pages/templates, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any sort of local dev copy of your site or a staging area? Personally that's how I would tread through this.

Establishing a good workflow can save your sanity and mitigate risk of down time for these sorts of things.